# I have copied an aspx application folder to my wwwroot directory in which all the files exist.I am getting the following error in IIS.

Tags: asp.net

`It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.`

I have copied an aspx application folder to my wwwroot directory in which all the files exist.

And I am accessing the Default.aspx file in the application directory.

Comment: From the error - it sounds like you need to right click on the virtual directory folder and convert it to application like it says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS you need to tell it that your directory is an application. Right click on the folder you have deployed to and select "Convert to application".

[image]

Comment: I did this and the icon of the folder also changed in IIS Manager. Still I am getting the same error.